# Rails render action that made the original request

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a contact form at `mysite.com/messages/new`. I like the idea of making this form available on all pages of my site. I have one *small* problem.

If I submit a POST request to `/messages` from the homepage and it fails validation, then `messages/new.html.erb` will be rendered (along with the error messages). Whilst I can live with this, I would prefer to render the template of the calling action (i.e. `home/index.html.erb`).

Currently I have the following in my messages controller:

```
def create
  @message = Message.new(params[:message])
  if @message.valid?
    MessageMailer.message_us(@message).deliver
    flash[:success] = "xthnxbai"
    redirect_to root_url
  else
    # this is where I want to change things
    render :new
  end
end
```

I've tried using the following:

```
else
  render :template => "#{request.controller}/#{request.action}"
```

But this gives:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `controller' for #<ActionDispatch::Request:0xa113168>):
```

Is it possible to tell rails to render the controller and action that initiated the POST request to my MessagesController?

Comment: It's not enough to render proper template, you also need to initialize proper instance variables, etc... Perhaps submitting the form remotely (AJAX) will be better?

Comment: Thanks, i have made sure that the instance variables are initialised, and I totally agree that I should do this with AJAX instead. You should submit that as an answer and I'll accept it, as I think it's probably going to turn out to be the best option.

Comment: controller_name and action_name variables should be set already in the controller code - but those point to the controller executing; you could use the referrer (`request.referer`), but sometimes this is nil, so have a fallback in that case

Comment: Thanks @house9 I'm now using AJAX to solve this problem, but thanks for the suggestion, I think `request.referer` might come in handy someday for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guess in this case submitting the form through AJAX will save you bacon. Especially considering how easy it can be done in Rails.

Comment: Agreed, I actually got AJAX working in less time than it took me to write this question!